# NewsPaper WP Theme - Additional Related Posts Filter by Time (divTag composer)

Tags: posts, post-meta, get-posts

I have specific situation here and really need help from someone who has experience with NewsPaper theme and tagDiv composer as well.

I want to add new function (or alter current, nevermind) that will allow me to add Related Posts block below content, but to use filter **Today's Posts** only (I will create that filter).

What I need to know is - does anyone knows where to add PHP code to alter current filter or to add new one. I am trying now for days, searching through strings, through files - can't find part in tagDiv composer where to edit/add code.

If anyone has this experience I will be more then grateful if he/she/... is willing to share knowledge about this. This is not code-oriented but experience-wise question.

Thank you all

Comment: You're going to have to ask the NewsPaper Theme and tagDiv Composer developers where the best place to add your code would be.  They may have provided hooks already.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.